# Updating Multiple columns of database with multiple text fields in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to update three fields in a three column of my database. Each time i run this, the last field get updated into all fields. Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

```
public function updateResult(Request $request)
{
$id = $request->student_id;

if(count($request->mark) > 0)
  {
      foreach($request->mark as $item=>$v){
        $data=array(
            'mark'=>$request->mark[$item],
            'grade'=>$request->grade[$item],
            'student_id'=>$request->student_id[$item],
        );
    Result::where('student_id', $id)->update($data);
  }
}

      return Redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed id here `$id = $request->student_id` and everytime you update `Result` you are updating same row(s) again.
I think you should do this:

```
public function updateResult(Request $request)
{
    // $id = $request->student_id; 
    // Note: The line above is no longer needed

    if(count($request->mark) > 0){
        foreach($request->mark as $item=>$v){
            $data=array(
                'mark'=>$request->mark[$item],
                'grade'=>$request->grade[$item]
                // Note: There is no need to include student_id here unless you actually intend to change the ID
            );

            Result::where('student_id', $request->student_id[$item])->update($data);
            // Note: In the line above, I replaced $id with $request->student_id[$item] to update the specific student
        }
    }

    return Redirect()->back();
}
```

Hope this helps you